# Can no longer edit the colors of shapes live in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is my memory bad? I've been using Photoshop since v1 (1993). I could have sworn, ever since they added shapes that you could select the shape and adjust the color of that shape live. But, today I made a blank document, drew a vector rectangle, then clicked the color button and the color of the shape does not change as I adjust the color in the color dialog. This makes it really hard to see what the results will be

Did I somehow mis-remember that photoshop used to live edit colors and now does not? Did it never live edit colors? If it does now, how do re-enable that feature?

See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_85IUF99L0

I'm running Photoshop 24.7.0 on an M1 Mac

Steps:

1. make a document 1000x1000 RGB color, 8bit
2. click the "Rectangle Tool (U)
3. draw a rectangle
4. on the right, in "properties", under "Appearance", click the "Fill" color
5. on the top right of colors, pick the "Color Picker"
6. Select colors in the color picker

What do I expect to happen?

I expect the shape to change colors as pick colors in the "Color Picker"

What happens inside. The colors don't change until I click "OK" and exit the Color Picker

By contrast, if I right click on the layer and pick to blend options, pick "color overlay", and pick "Set color of overlay" the same color picker appears but this one is live. I don't have to click "Ok" to see the colors change.

How do I get the shape's color to be live?

Comment: double click the rectangle thumbnail in the Layers panel.